# Showing error for last element to first

Tags: jquery, struts2, jquery-validate

While validating form it is working properly but

It is first giving message for `Description` then for `Code` then for `Name`.
but I want that validation should be first for `Name` then for `Code` then for `Description`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#added").validate({
        rules: {
            Name: {
                required: true
            },
            Code: {
                required: true
            },
            Description: {
                required: true
            },

        },

        messages: {
            Name: {
                required: "Enter Name"
            },
            Code: {
                required: "Enter code"
            },

            Description: {
                required: "Enter Description"
            },
        },

        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            $("#error-messages").html(error); // error container
        }
    });​
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="error-messages"></div>
<s:form action="added" id="added" method="post" >
   <s:textfield name="Name" id="Name" label="Name" labelposition="top" />
   <s:textarea name="Code" id="Code" rows="10" cols="50" 
                 label="Code" labelposition="top"/>

   <s:textarea name="Description" id="Description" rows="5" cols="50"
                 label="Description" labelposition="top"/>
<s:form>
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Tried reversing the validation rule order?

Comment: Duplicate of this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679480/specifiy-the-order-of-the-validators-in-jquery-validate-plugin ?

Comment: @SamuelCaillerie I am not getting the Duplicate questions could you please explain with above example

Comment: @Manish : the answer proposed in the question that I proposed can be used in order to customize the order but asked to add the element one by one, which is not really maintainable -> thus I agree with you, this is not a duplicate! And I have added a possible answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The [jQuery validation plugin](http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js) retrieves the elements in order of the DOM (see `$.validator.prototype.elements` function, l. 461).

So a solution in order to validate from last to first element is to patch this function with this code in our own script section :

```
$.validator.prototype.elements = function() {
    var validator = this,
        rulesCache = {};

    // select all valid inputs inside the form (no submit or reset buttons)
    return 
        $(  // Added this in order to re-encapsulate in a jQuery object the reversed array (see below)
        $(this.currentForm)
        .find("input, select, textarea")
        .not(":submit, :reset, :image, [disabled]")
        .not( this.settings.ignore )
        .filter(function() {
            if ( !this.name && validator.settings.debug && window.console ) {
                console.error( "%o has no name assigned", this);
            }

            // select only the first element for each name, and only those with rules specified
            if ( this.name in rulesCache || !validator.objectLength($(this).rules()) ) {
                return false;
            }

            rulesCache[this.name] = true;
            return true;
        })
        .get().reverse()  // Added this in order to reverse the array order
    );
}
```